Problema con campo fecha en sistema LINUX
A ver si alguien me da una posible solucíon
Tengo un archivo PHP donde muestro un campo "datetime-local" que le paso desde una base de datos
<input type="datetime-local" name="FechaInicio" min="2024-01-01" id="FechaInicial" value ="<?php echo $horaInicio?>" data-initial-value="<?php echo $horaInicio?>">

Este archivo PHP lleva asociado un script JS donde hago la transformación para que me muestre el campo en el formato "DD/MM/AAAA HH:MM", con el siguiente código:
const [datePart, timePart] = InputString.split(' ');
const [hours, minutes, seconds] = timePart.split(':');
const dateObject = new Date(`${datePart}T${hours.padStart(2, '0')}:${minutes}`);
const year = dateObject.getFullYear();
const month = String(dateObject.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
const day = String(dateObject.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
const formattedHours = String(dateObject.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
const formattedMinutes = String(dateObject.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
const formattedDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${formattedHours}:${formattedMinutes}`;

Mi problema es que en sistemas Windows si que me muestra el formato como deseo, pero en sistemas Linux me muestra el formato "AA/MM/DD HH:MM"

¿y no será que te muestra ese formato por la configuración de tu linux?  En mi Ubuntu el campo datetime-local me muestra el formato dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm sin problemas. Es decir, eso depende de la configuración del idioma de tu navegador seguramente o quizás de tu sistema linux.  Yo no me arriesgaria a toquetearlo después con javascript, pues es impredecible el idioma del navegador de tus visitantes. Simplemente espera el resultado en PHP (o lo que uses de backend) que te vendrá correctamente y lo podrás evaluar y tratar mejor.
